# Error in all the classes files: R cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Example code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Error:

```
R cannot be resolved
```

There's this error in all the classes files, and I can't get rid of it.

I already checked the XML files, there are no errors.

I already made sure that I didn't accidentally import "android.R".

The problem started when I tried to Clean and Rebuild the project.

Comment: Did you update the SDK Tools recently?

Comment: Try to Clean and Rebuild

Comment: @edoardotognoni yes I did. I updated it yesterday, but it worked after I updated it just started today...

Comment: @juned I already tried to Clean and Rebuild the project...

Comment: I had the same issue. Is your gen folder empty?

Comment: Is there an import R in your files? If so remove that import from all files

Comment: @edoardotognoni Yes. The gen folder is empty.

Comment: Ok,see my answer just below

Comment: @EliRevah you can try the accepted answer in the link. Not sure if it helps. but give it a try.

Comment: Try to Clean if not generated then restart eclipse..bcoz i face d same problem also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already updated the SDK tools, re-open the SDK manager and check under the "Tools" section that "Android SDK Build tools" are installed and eventually, update them. That made the trick for me yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your R is generated properly inside the "gen" folder.Check if there are any libraries missing which are added as dependencies from project properties.
 Also make sure that there are no issues which is preventing the app from generating R file. Go to Window > Show view> Problems and it will show you whats missing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Delete your Gen folder (It will be automatically created afterwards).

2) Clean you project.

See the miracle. :)

Comment: Now I did what you told me, and the Gen folder isn't being created again.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

```
1.Check whether there are errors in your xml file.

2.Try to clean the project and run it.
```

Comment: I already checked for errors in the XML files, and cleaning the project is what ruined it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I made an update with sdk manager, and I had the same problem as you.
I fixed the issue: I have updated another time the android sdk (with the sdk manager tool), then I check update from eclipse for install the updated ADT plugin and I rebuid my project. 
"Android sdk Build-tools" from  Android sdk manager is now rev 17 and now it is OK.
I think the issue is from adt plugin from eclipse