# Eclipse clean corrupts android project

Tags: android, eclipse, project, corrupt

When I do eclipse clean on an android project, it no longer is able to generate the GEN files for the project (gen folder becomes empty). The project was previously imported and ran FINE on my phone UNTIL I did clean and could no longer compile because of R.java not found. I could not find any project property changes as a result of the clean that could have been gotton messed up. So I don't know what the cause is of the corruption!

My version:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
```

I never before had the problem that clean made a non-working project from a perfectly fine working project.

Comment: Updated to ADT r22? Did you install Build-tools in SDK Manager?

Comment: Got to Android tools and  in that select "Fix project properties" and run..

Comment: Ok problem ist solved thank you laalto for that!! @Subburaj just for interest: where exactly is that menu option "Android tools" in eclipse? Can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer: [Error in all the classes files: R cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604454/error-in-all-the-classes-files-r-cannot-be-resolved/16604608#16604608)

The fact is that probably you're missing the Android Build tools. Or you just need to update them.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some error in your xml files. Double-check each file to find any error. The ADT does not generate the R.java in the gen folder if there is atleast 1 error in the xml files.

For more info see this question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145518/603125