# R can not be resolved error in source files after upgrading the ADT 22

Tags: android, adt

> I updated the **ADT plugin to 22 API version**.
>       After upgrading, my projects won't compile,
>       project's `gen` folder is also empty. project's `src`
>       files also gives error.
>       After installing latest Android build tools, projects gives an error.
>       suggest me solutions.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604454/error-in-all-the-classes-files-r-cannot-be-resolved/16604608#comment23869049_16604608

Comment: Re-open your SDK Manager and check if all packages are up to date.

Comment: error : R can't be resolved error in source files

Comment: Check answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642604/eclipse-error-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/16643060#16643060

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16596990/115145

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are missing the Build tools or probably you didn't update them. Open SDK manager and in the general section, make sure that Build Tools are up to date.

Comment: Redundancy is not allowed as you already have answered earlier with the same content.

Comment: I posted it as an answer but I didn't see that it was putted automatically as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, after updating Eclipse and ADT. I don't know what the "proper" way is to resolve it, but I eventually resorted to completely removing Eclipse/ADT and doing a clean re-install using the latest ADT Bundle. Everything worked perfectly thereafter.